# Why my code doesn't work when i change line of pointer=&number;?

Tags: c

I used the `malloc` function in this example. Problem is when I remove the line of `pointer=&number;` or move to different line  I can't receive number entered from keyboard. I am trying to receive numbers entered by keyboard.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(){
    int *pointer,number;
    printf("Please write a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    pointer=(int *)malloc(number*(sizeof(int)));
    if(pointer!=NULL){
        pointer=&number;  /*When i try to move this line to below or to up i can't receive number in address of pointer.*/
        printf("Number entered: %d\n",*pointer);
    }else{
        printf("Memory is not divided.");
        return 0;
    }
    free(pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you `malloc` and then overwrite the result? It is a memory leak. And freeing the new value is a bad idea. Also please show what it means "below or to up.."

Comment: Why is this tagged with `c++`?

Comment: Thank you so much for answers. Dear Eugene Sh. i am trying to learn malloc function usage. I understand how to use but problem is i am trying to take and print value of pointer variable. without writing "pointer=&number;" code i can't receive numbers in address of pointer. one more subject is you asked to me "below or to up" what does it mean. I am trying to explain with move to up for example "pointer=&number;" code in line 10 for example. When i move this code to line 8 its doesn't work.

**Best Regards**

Comment: dear Weather Vane, when i try your idea its returned me;
 **Please write a number: 5                                                                                                Number entered: 7936784** 

When i add again * to pointer its returning me 0

Comment: @ahmet yaman There is nothing to discuss. The program does not make any sense. The question should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pointer = &number;
```

should be

```
*pointer = number;
```

You're replace the pointer that you got with `malloc()`, with a pointer to the local variable, which causes a memory leak. And then when you later call `free(pointer);`, you're trying to free a pointer to a local variable, not the memory that was allocated, which causes undefined behavior.

And if you're only storing 1 number into the allocated memory, there's no need to multiply when calling `malloc()`. It should just be

```
pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Full tested script:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(){
    int *pointer,number;
    printf("Please write a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    pointer=malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(pointer!=NULL){
        *pointer=number;
        printf("Number entered: %d\n",*pointer);
    }else{
        printf("Memory is not divided.");
        return 0;
    }
    free(pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: its doesn't worked. I updated thoose codes to line 

**Best Regards**

Comment: #include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(){
    int *pointer,number;
    printf("Please write a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    pointer=(int *)malloc(number*(sizeof(int)));
    if(pointer!=NULL){
        *pointer=number;  /*When i try to move this line to below or to up i can't receive number in address of pointer.*/
        printf("Number entered: %d\n",*pointer);
    }else{
        printf("Memory is not divided.");
        return 0;
    }
    free(pointer);
    return 0;
}

Yes its worked thank you a lot )) can you example where was my mistake?